# Change add to cart is_purchasable notice in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, product

I would like to change the notice 'Sorry, this product cannot be purchased' to  'Sorry, the product [product name] cannot be purchased.'

I've found it in the `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method source code and below it's an extract of what I would like to change:

```
if ( ! $product_data->is_purchasable() ) {
   #the current line
   #throw new Exception( __( 'Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.', 'woocommerce' ) ); 
   # i want to replace for this one
   throw new Exception(sprintf( __( 'Sorry, the product &quot;%s&quot; cannot be purchased.', 'woocommerce' ),  $product_data->get_name() ) );
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a hook or filter or something in my `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following hooked function in WordPress **`gettext`** filter hook:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'renaming_purshasable_notice', 100, 3 );
function renaming_purshasable_notice( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $text === 'Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.' ) {
        $post_title = get_post($GLOBALS['_POST']['add-to-cart'])->post_title;

        $translated_text = sprintf( __( 'Sorry, the product %s cannot be purchased.', $domain ), '&quot;'.$post_title.'&quot;' );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work very well, but I think I omitted some information, this message occour when I use the **order again** and the product doesen't exist or is a draft. So it doesen't show the product name, but shows "Twitter"

Comment: @MarcoAntonioSantanna Thanks… If I find something functional for you particular case explained in this comment, I will message you.

Comment: Thankyou @LoicTheAztec

Comment: I have a similar problem could someone take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081139/woocommerce-is-purchasable-hook-results-in-sorry-this-product-cannot-be-purc